# operator overloading with and or statements

Tags: python-3.x, operators

I am not getting how the working of "**and**" and "**or**" statement is going on the program. Help me understanding its working properly.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a=a
    def show(self):
        print(self.a)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self,b):
        self.a=b
    def __str__(self):
        return "({0})".format(self.a)
    def __add__(self,other):
        return self.a+other.a

E=B("Tony")
R=B("Stark")

print(E or R)
print(E and R)
print(E+R)
```

Comment: what is it that you dont get?

Comment: Check if my explanation makes sense to you

Answer (score 0):

Your class essentially represents the string `Tony` and `Stark`.

For the **or** operator, The first value is evaluated, if it evaluates to True, it is printed, otherwise we move to the second value and evaluate it, and print it

In the example below, the first string evaluates to True, since `bool(string)` always evaluates to True

```
In [15]: bool('Tony')                                                                                 
Out[15]: True
In [17]: bool('Stark')                                                                                
Out[17]: True
In [12]: 'Tony' or 'Stark'                                                                            
Out[12]: 'Tony'
In [14]: 'Stark' or 'Tony'                                                                            
Out[14]: 'Stark'
```

But if you have `None` which evaluates to False, we will see a different result.

```
In [23]: bool(None)                                                                                   
Out[23]: False
In [21]: 'Stark' or None                                                                              
Out[21]: 'Stark'
In [22]: 'Tony' or None                                                                               
Out[22]: 'Tony'
In [18]: None or 'Tony'                                                                               
Out[18]: 'Tony'
In [20]: None or 'Stark'                                                                              
Out[20]: 'Stark'
```

For the **and** operator, only when both values are true, the value is evaluated to true and the second value is picked

```
In [24]: 'Tony' and 'Stark'                                                                           
Out[24]: 'Stark'
In [25]: 'Stark' and 'Tony'                                                                           
Out[25]: 'Tony'
```

But if one of them evaluates to False, No value will be shown.

```
In [31]: 'Stark' and None                                                                             
In [32]: 'Tony' and None                                                                              
In [33]: None and 'Tony'                                                                              In [34]: None and 'Stark'
```

Comment: Thanku for your help.. It really made me understand the working of and  , or statements

Comment: Glad to be of help :) Please accept and upvote my answer if it helped you :)